# ERROR TypeError: is undefined. When give data from service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a handler that will create an array of categories depending on whether there are “categories” for this “resource” or not. The last method throws an error. 
ERROR TypeError: "this.allProjectResources is undefined"

```
import { ResourceCategory } from './resourceCategory';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resource } from './resource';
import { HttpService } from '../project/http.service';
import { isNullOrUndefined } from 'util';

@Injectable()
export class ResourceService {

    public allProjectResources: Resource[];
    public allResourceCategories: ResourceCategory[];

    uniqueResCategories = new Set();

    constructor(private http: HttpService) { }

    getAllResourcesByProjId(projid: number) {
        if (!(isNullOrUndefined(this.allProjectResources))) {
            this.allProjectResources.length = 0;
        }
        this.http.getAllResourcesById(projid).subscribe((data: Resource[]) => 
        this.allProjectResources = data);
    }
    getAllResourceCategories() {
        this.http.getAllResourceCategories().subscribe((data: ResourceCategory[]) =>
        this.allResourceCategories = data);

    }
    getAllUniqieResourceCategories(){
        this.allProjectResources.forEach(resource => {
            this.allResourceCategories.forEach(function (category) {
                if (resource.resourceCategoryId == category.id) {
                    this.uniqueResCategories.add(category.name);
                    console.log(category.name);
                };
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize class variables to empty array

```js
public allProjectResources: Resource[] = [];
public allResourceCategories: ResourceCategory[] = [];
```

Also, you should be assigning empty array in `getAllResourcesByProjId()` method instead of mutating the length property

```js
getAllResourcesByProjId(projid: number) {
        if (!(isNullOrUndefined(this.allProjectResources))) {
           // this.allProjectResources.length = 0;
            this.allProjectResources = [];
        }
        ...
}
```